# .Net 5 - Azure Pipeline - The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly' specified could not be found

Tags: azure-pipelines, webdeploy, blazor-webassembly, .net-5

I just upgraded a Blazor Web Assembly solution to .Net 5 and I'm getting the following error in an Azure Pipeline in the NuGet Command step:

> error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly' specified could not be found

The azure-pipelines.yml file is the following:

```
trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: 'SomeProjectNew.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: 'SomeProjectNew.sln'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=SomeProject-demo /p:Password=$(SomeProjectDemoWebDeployPassword)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Am I missing some step in the pipeline configuration to make this work with .Net 5 and the new blazor sdk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using .Net 5, instead of using Nuget command, try to use `Use .net core task`and `Dotnet core task` with restore command.

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 5.0.100-rc.1.20452.10'
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '5.0.100'
    includePreviewVersions: true

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
```

It's strongly recommended to use `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` tasks for projects that target `.net core`. See [this statement from Nuget task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops):

Also take a look at this similar question here: [Azure CI pipeline for Blazor .NET 5 doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64232919/azure-ci-pipeline-for-blazor-net-5-doesnt-work)

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I'll try that now. Why Release Candidate though? Isn't the RTM version available for this?

Comment: Setting version to '5.0.100' and removing includePreviewVersions worked. And then just a second step with dotnet publish. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody else is after the full yml file, here is what I ended up with:

```
trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:

- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Install .NET 5 SDK'
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '5.x'
    
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Restore Nuget Packages'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: 'SomeSolution.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: '.nuget/NuGet.config'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Publish to Azure'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: 'SomeProjectFolder/SomeWebProject.csproj'
    arguments: '/p:PublishProfile=profile-name /p:Password=$(WebDeployPassword)'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false
```

My publish profile uses web deploy to deploy the app to an Azure App Service. This approach relies on a '.nuget/NuGet.config' file in source control, and a secret variable $(WebDeployPassword) defined on the pipeline ([Secret Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables)).