# Building azure pipeline with .NET 5.0, warnings?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

So am trying to build a pipeline in Azure for a WebApi app developed in .Net 5.0, however when I run the standard yaml pipeline (asp.net core) I get the following warnings:

```
Tvattstugan\Tvattstugan.csproj(0,0): Warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Cors 5.2.7' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

I checked out a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64830501/building-net-5-0-project-azure-devops-pipeline) on SO and tried experimenting with answers from that thread to comment out the nuget tasks and insert UseDotNet task but that only gave me more warnings so commented out those suggestions.

**If anybody could explain the procedure and how to get around this I would be very appreciative. Here is my pipeline.yml:**

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
inputs:
restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

# - task: UseDotNet@2
#   inputs:
#     packageType: 'sdk'
#     version: '5.0.x'

# - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
#   displayName: 'dotnet build'
#   inputs:
#     command: 'build'

- task: VSBuild@1
inputs:
solution: '$(solution)'
msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
inputs:
platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you use VSBuild and VSTest instead of dotnet command line tool?

Comment: Not really, just used info from somewhere where it said VSBuild and VSTest. 

How should the syntax look instead? Thanks